# Removing entries from a table where it's values already exist in the table

Tags: sql, algorithm, t-sql, duplicates

I'm starting with this example table (#temp2):

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | x
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | x
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 | x
| 7 | 4 | x
|---|---|
```

This is a table of transaction keys that I want to be deleted from another existing table. It represents transactions that negate other transactions, where a negates b or vice-versa.  So I cannot have a single a negating multiple b or a single b negating multiple a. I have some logic that I thought would do it but there is a problem. With my existing logic it will look to see if a or b is a duplicate and delete it if it is. The problem is, if I want a row to be deleted I would like it to 'free' up the value that wasn't the reason for deletion. I hope this isn't too confusing. But from my example I put x's next to each row I want deleted. Currently my algorithm is deleting too many rows. The row (6,5) gets deleted because there already exists a '5' in the second row, but that row is getting deleted (since '2' can't negate '4' and '5') so this 'frees up' the '5' to negate entry 6.

This is my current code, but it is deleting too many rows:

```
delete t
from #temp2 t
    where exists(select * from #temp2 
                 where b = t.b 
                    and a < t.a)
  or exists(select * from #temp2
                 where a = t.a 
                    and b < t.b)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think essentially what I'm looking for is for it to do the delete immediately (before it looks at the next value), instead of keeping the table constant through the whole delete process. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Why (2,5) is deleted, but not (2,4) ? Since you are using sentences like `the second row` and `the next value`, I guess that you are assumming that there is some order of rows in the table. Basically **there is no any order of the rows in the table**. The table is a set of tuples, and a set has no order. There is only the order you get when specyfing an `ORDER BY some_column` clause.

Comment: You're right, there is no order, it doesn't matter. I was just referring to the example I had above.  And either (2,5) or (2,4) could be deleted and it would work, I just have it deleting the greatest value for now.

Comment: The pairs {a,b} are unordered? I mean the resulting graph is undirected ?